# object empty inside calling function using pointer as argument

Tags: c++, object, pointers

I am learning C++ with pointers and trying to program a small game. I have a class PlayerManager which should create players and save them in a file.
The code compiles but when I call the method savePlayer, the pointer inside the method is valid but I cannot access the object to which the pointer is pointing.

I have searched for similar problems on internet but did not find anything similar. I may not be looking for the right keywords as I have no idea where this comes from.
I checked before the function is called and the pointer is working and I can access the object.
Inside the calling function, the pointer still has the right address but I cannot access the object. Nothing is returned.
After the calling function the pointer is still valid and the object accessible. (see //Comments in the code below)

Here are my two functions inside my PlayerManager class.

```
void PlayerManager::createPlayer()
{
    Player *playerPtr = new Player();
    std::string name;
    std::cout << "Name: ";
    std::cin >> name;                // I entered for instance John
    std::cout << std::endl;
    playerPtr->setName(name);
    std::cout << "PlayerPtr name before savePlayer: " << playerPtr->getName() << std::endl; // Outputs John
    std::cout << "playerPtr before savePlayer: " << playerPtr << std::endl;  // Ouputs the address
    this->savePlayer(playerPtr);
    std::cout << "PlayerPtr name after savePlayer but inside createPlayer: " << playerPtr->getName() << std::endl; // Outputs: John
    delete playerPtr;
}

void PlayerManager::savePlayer(Player* playerPtr) // the called method
{
    std::cout << "playerPtr inside savePlayer: " << playerPtr << std::endl;  // Outputs the address
    std::cout << "PlayerPtr name inside savePlayer: " << playerPtr->getName() << std::endl; // Outputs nothing
    std::string const fileName = "Players/"+playerPtr->getName()+".txt";
    std::cout << fileName << std::endl; // Outputs Players/.txt
    std::ofstream myFile = std::ofstream(fileName.c_str());
    if(myFile)
    {
        std::cout << "Enregistrement du nouveau joueur." << std::endl; // The code launches but no file is created.
        myFile << "{"<< std::endl;
        myFile << "name: " + playerPtr->getName() <<std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "Erreur d'enregistrement du fichier." << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to access the object created in createPlayer method inside the savePlayer method by passing a pointer but I just get an empty string for

```
playerPtr->getName()
```

I don't understand how the object is accessible before the call of the method and after but not inside as the address is still valid.

**EDIT1**
Thank you for guiding me to the obvious mistake !
Because of recuring crash of code:blocks my getName() method was deleted before I could save it and I did not think about checking it. By writing the following getName() it worked:

```
std::string Player::getName() const 
{
   return m_name; 
}
```

Yet I do not understand why and How I got an output in createPlayer() although the method getName() was empty. Is this normal ?

**EDIT 2**
I'll create a new question for this strange behavior.

Comment: Please post your getter function `getName()`

Comment: Cannot reproduce by adding correct code around your functions. The error comes from not shown code. You should provide a [mcve] if you want help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have should work fine. My only guess is that there's something fishy about your getter function `getName()`.

I presume you have something along these lines?

```
const std::string &getName() const
{
    return name;
}
```

Online code example: https://rextester.com/INHG32142

Comment: Interesting. I had my return method as follows:
```std::string Player::getName() const
{
    return m_name; 
}
```
Yet my code:blocks is bugging every day on ubuntu and the method got deleted. That is where the error came from. My getName was actually emtpy. But then Why did it return something inside the method createPlayer although getName() was empty ?

Comment: @Shaker81: A getter function should return a `const &` of the member and the function should be marked as `const`. Your getter function returns a copy. This can be problematic in some cases, but it's ok in this code. If your function got deleted, then the code shouldn't even compile. However, if you are using an IDE, then sometimes a shadow build keeps reference of your functions and works when it should fail. I really don't know what could have gone wrong in your case, but that's my guess.